# composer autoload not work in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0, composer-php, autoload

i'm install cakeresque (plugin) in cakephp
whene i'm load plugin in bootstrap.php file :

> CakePlugin::load(array(
>       'CakeResque' => array('bootstrap' => true)
>   ));

and add composer autoload in core.php like this

> require_once dirname(**DIR**) . '/Vendor/autoload.php';

show me this error :

> Error: Class 'CakeResque\CakeResque' not found 
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\app\Plugin\CakeResque\config\bootstrap.php
>   Line: 23
>
> app
>   - Config
>   -- bootstrap.php
>   -- core.php
>   - Plugin
>   -- CakeResque
>   --- config
>   --- src
>   ---- Locale
>   ---- Shell
>   ---- tmp
>   ---- CakeResque.php
>   ---- CakeResqueBootstrap.php
>   ---- Resque_Job_Creator.php
>   --- tests
>   --- vendor
>   - Vendor
>   -- bin
>   -- composer
>   -- autoload.php